# Black screen on boot after updating libgdk-pixbuf2

Tags: boot, kernel, 16.10

I updated through the update manager about half an hour ago, it asked me to restart so I did, but now I keep booting up to a black screen that only shows the cursor.

If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, I can log in through the console, but otherwise I'm just met with a cursor and a black screen.

This is on the latest Dell XPS 13, with the i5 processor. Ubuntu 16.10.

I would appreciate any help at all! Thanks!

I've also tried booting with older kernels in boot up options but I still get the black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can log on with your CTRL+ ALT +F6. why not reinstall `lightdm` and reinstall `unity desktop`. The this two and give us feeds.

Comment: Dude, thank you thank you thank you thank you thank!!!!!! SOOO MUCH. That worked, I'm back in and typing this from the very laptop that had the problem, thanks!